# updating form creates new object in database

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am fresher to work on play framework-1.2.5
I have created form and saving it in database.Till this fine,now when i trying to update any object, will create new object(row) in database.
This should not happens.Is there any solution.

```
ID  Name       
===========
1   EMP1.0          
2   EMP1.1      
3   EMP1.2      
4   EMP1.3
```

This is example of database structure. Same object added as new new to database while updating and saving it.

My Model code :

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public SupplierTypeModel supplierTypeModel;
```

Controller code :

```
supplier.edit("supplier",params.all());
validation.valid(supplier);
supplier.save();
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/1.2.5/index.html) is deprecated. use [model object binding](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#objectbinding) instead. Remember, if parameters have model.id then it will retrieve the model from db, so you can edit it.

Comment: Thanks. but i tried this one Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "supplier", supplier); but problem not solved.

Comment: public static void editAction(Long id){
   models.Supplier supplier = models.Supplier.findById(id);
   Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "supplier", supplier);
   index();
}

This is my code.I am passing id from my view.